# Integrating "really simple history" with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In trying to solve the "ajax back button" problem I have found the [Really Simply History](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/) library.

Has anyone tried to integrate it with Rails?

It's plain old javascript so it seems like it should integrate just fine, but I know next to nothing about JS itself, so I'm not too confident in trying to do the integration without a tutorial or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this blog](http://lindsaar.net/2008/2/22/history-buttons-with-ajax-and-ruby-on-rails) (which doesn't show up at all when i google or search yahoo for "Rails really simple history"

Comment: Thanks. One would think I would have been able to find that. But it got me going in the right direction.